# Yii framework первый запуск?

Tags: framework, yii

Веб гуру, подскажите, что я делаю не так.

Установил yii 1.1.16 на денвер,
иду в `Z:\home\yii\www\protected\config там в database.php`, раскомментировал строки подключения:

```
            <?php

            // This is the database connection configuration.
            return array(
                'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
                // uncomment the following lines to use a MySQL database

                'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdrive',
                'emulatePrepare' => true,
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'root',
                'charset' => 'utf8',

            );
```

Но залогиниться не получается?

Comment: конфиги тут правильные настроены?

Comment: все по умолчанию

Comment: вы уверены, что в базе данных вообще что-то есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
```

ну это-то убери

Comment: @Shrek, оно, конечно, правильно, но @anunak с его проблемой это не поможет

Comment: @Etki видимо, помогло :)